# Как подключить библиотеку Android-gallery?

Tags: android, kotlin

Библиотека находится тут https://github.com/redmadrobot-spb/android-gallery. Все делаю как написано, в результате получаю ошибку при запуске приложения:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот если надо файлы с моим подключением:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.32"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

И вот еще:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "net.maioya.pzd"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.redmadrobot.gallery:android-gallery:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Какое "при запуске приложения"? Оно даже не компилится, до запуска дело не доходит. Попробуйте добавить в список репозиторий `mavenCentral()`, `jcenter()` уже давно нормально не работает.

Comment: jcenter() там было добавлено я же в коде написал mavenCentral() добавил не помогает Спасибо

Comment: А вы имели ввиду вместо jcenter заменить счас попробую

Comment: Нет ее на MavenCentral, только на Jitpack.io, см. мой ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Автор билиотеки приводит неверные сведения о подключении билиотеки к проекту.

Правильная информация

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.redmadrobot-spb:android-gallery:1.0.0'
}
```

Взято отсюда:
https://jitpack.io/#redmadrobot-spb/android-gallery

Comment: Большое человеческое спасибо, кажется запустилось. Принимаю правильный ответ.